# File input separation

Tags: c++, file, input, output

Currently, I'm writing a program for a class, and we have to use file input and output. She gave us a file, which is 8 different sets of 7 numbers (all integers). We have to have the user enter which line they'd like read, and then output the highest number, lowest number, sum of the set of numbers, and average of the set. I'm having an issue getting XCode to read just one line of numbers. I haven't had much practice with the `getline()` function, if that's even a solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Start with something simple that you can do. Try. Fail. Redo. Think. Succeed. Then try something harder. Eventually you'll be able to do this.

Comment: _'I'm having an issue getting xcode to read just one line of numbers'_ could you be more elaborate on this, can you show some code you've tried.

Comment: A hint: Check what you can do with a line using `std::ostringstream`

Comment: linput.open("Lab5input.rtf");
    
    linput>>num1>>num2>>num3>>num4>>num5>>num6>>num7;
    
    cout<<num1<<num2<<num3<<num4<<num5<<num6<<num7<<endl;

Just trying to get it to display the numbers isn't working like I expected.

I want it to display:
346 130 982 90 656 117 595 (without the spaces.)

Instead, it shows: 32767174533648800000

Comment: @RaymondAaron Could you put that code in your question please, Hard to read in a comment ...

Comment: You want to use an array, not 7 discrete variables: `lintput >> num[0] >> num[1] >> num[2] >> num[3] >> num[4] >> num[5] >> num[6];`.  To get going, echo each line as it is read — just read the numbers and echo them back, all 8 times.  Then you can refine it.

Answer (score 0):

Granted this is a homework assignment, this sacrifices efficiency to show you know a certain subject, but the code should give you a vague idea.

Note** This only works if you user can only enter one line and the program exits

```
cout << "enter line...";
cin >> line;
//error check line to make sure it is in bounds

///loops through each set of 7 numbers LINE times

//loop through line(FOR LOOP)

    //read in the 7 vars

//end loop

//loop through array(FOR LOOP)

    //add array[i] onto sum
    //is this number higher than the var HIGH? if yes then set high equal to array element
    //is this number lower than the low var? if yes then set low equal to array element

//end loop
```